# Distance between middles of trapezoid's diagonals middles

Tags: geometry

What is a proof for a fact that the distance between middles of trapezoid's diagonals is equal to half of the difference of it's basis' lengths?

Comment: Use midpoint theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Using midpoint theorem

Let $MN$ is the median, $AB$ is the lower base, $CD$ is the upper base,

$AM=DM$,and,$BN=CN$

and intersection of median of trapezium and diagonals $K$ and $L$

$$KN=\frac{a}{2}$$

$$LN=\frac{c}{2}$$

$$KL=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{c}{2}=\frac{a-c}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome